# Problema con htaccess al redirigir www y https en .com.mx

Tags: .htaccess, dominio

Hola tengo un dominio con .com.mx el cual quiero sea siempre dirigido con https y www pero al parecer el siguiente código no esta funcionando.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Ese código previamente lo he usado en .com

¿Acaso hay algo distinto cuando es .com.mx?

El error que me marca es el 403

Comment: Revisaste si tu proveedor tiene la opción de FORZAR el HTTPS? Si ese es el caso, esto no sería necesario en el httaccess

Comment: Descubrí que el problema era que el archivo tenia acceso denegado, me siento estúpido al no revisar eso antes :c